# Rubymine (Ruby): Why can't I run rspec from within the IDE?

Tags: ruby, sdk, ide, rubygems, rubymine

If I run the following command from the terminal I am able to run the rspec test cases successfully.

**bundle exec rspec spec/requests/api/contacts/v3_get_tags_spec.rb**

However if I am in the Rubymine IDE and do:

1- Right click on the file

2- Select "Run"

Then i get the following error message.

**"in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)"**

Also i am seeing a lot of errors related to gems not found, i feel link Rubymine is not configured correctly. What am i missing?

Note: Both the terminal and the IDE are running in the same root directory. I am pretty sure there is a problem with the configuration of the IDE. I checked the preference setting and it is using the same version of ruby as the one I am running in the termina.

Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: because running the file is not the same as running the spec test [See Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/run-debug-configuration-rspec.html) for full instructions on set up

Comment: RubyMine has its own environment separate from the command line. You need to configure which Ruby it will use (if you have more than 1). There's a RubyMine Slack team you can join and ask the question there too (web search "rubymine slack").

Comment: Did you find out about this? I have the same problem now.